# mysql force order of results found to match order of IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, having, sql-in

This question is different to a [commonly asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986731/how-to-select-mysql-rows-in-the-order-of-in-clause) about ordering the final results by the IN clause.

I would like to force the results returned by the query that contains the IN clause, to match the order of the IN clause.

[This is the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461743/combining-mysql-queries-that-recycle-multiple-self-joins) that I am working from.

I'd like to alter the query below so that a row containing `progress=2` occurs before `progress=4` and `progress=7` for each `session_id` when ordering the `formation_page_hits` table by `datetime`.

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    (
    SELECT  session_id
    FROM    formation_page_hits
    WHERE   progress IN (2, 4, 7)
            AND datetime >= '2011-03-23'
            AND datetime < '2011-03-24'
    GROUP BY
            session_id
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT progress) = 3
    ) q
```

These entries

```
datetime,               session_id, progress
('2011-03-01 01:02:11', 'abc',      2)
('2011-03-01 01:02:12', 'abc',      4)
('2011-03-01 01:02:13', 'abc',      7)
```

should be a match for the query, but:

```
datetime,               session_id, progress
('2011-03-01 01:02:11', 'abc',      4)
('2011-03-01 01:02:12', 'abc',      2)
('2011-03-01 01:02:13', 'abc',      7)
```

should not be a match.

Additionally:

```
datetime,               session_id, progress
('2011-03-01 01:02:11', 'abc',      4)
('2011-03-01 01:02:12', 'abc',      2)
('2011-03-01 01:02:13', 'abc',      4)
('2011-03-01 01:02:14', 'abc',      7)
```

should be a match.

Comment: (2, 4, 7) is strictly ascending order. Is your example data special or you want always to use ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common way is to double self-join to end up with a three way join ON ascending date time.  That, however, is hardly a well performing query.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT  session_id, group_concat(concat('|',progress,'/') order by datetime) list
    FROM    formation_page_hits
    WHERE   progress IN (2, 4, 7)
            AND datetime >= '2011-03-23'
            AND datetime < '2011-03-24'
    GROUP BY session_id
    HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT progress) = 3
) X
where list like '%|2/%|4/%|7/%'
```